# Are there languages generated by linear grammar which aren't regular?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars, context-free

Are there languages generated by linear grammer which aren't regular?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course. Look at the first example on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_grammar):

$\qquad S \to aSb \mid \varepsilon$

is linear and generates $\{a^nb^n \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, a [non-regular language](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-not-regular).

If you mean left-linear, or right-linear, then no - they are equivalent to REG.